# Remove GET variable symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am working on symfony 2.2 and I have an issue, when I try to delete a get variable such as message in this url : myurl?message=mymessage

It doesn't work.

```
public function myfunction1() { 
....    
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_admin_credit', array("message" => $message))); // generate the url : myurl?message=mymessage
}

/**
* @Route("/credit", name="_admin_credit")
*/ 
public function getCreditAction($) { 
$request = $this->getRequest(); 

$message = $request->query->get('message'); // this works 
$request->query->remove('message'); // this work in the function but do not change the url

return $this->render('MyBundle:Admin:credit.html.twig', array(
                     'message' => $message
                ));  // still the same url : myurl?message=mymessage
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`$request->query->remove('message');` will remove the paramter from the [ParameterBag](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html) only.

If you want to remove it from the URL you have to [redirect](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting) to an URL without the parameter.

In Addition, if you want to keep the value of `message`, you can use a [Flash Message](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages) to store it between two requests. This means: you can get the parameter, store it, redirect to another URL and recall the value once from the session.